# Get query result according to merged array

Tags: posts, wp-query, order

1st query selecting the records that are found

```
$old_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => '_sale_price_dates_to',
            'value' => $timenow,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'numeric'
        ) ,
        array(
            'key' => '_sale_price_dates_to',
            'value' => '',
            'compare' => '!='
        ) ,
        array(
            'key' => 'wccaf_location_zipcode',
            'value' => array(
                '78774',
                '73344'
            ) ,
            'compare' => 'IN'
        )
    ) ,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $cat_id
        )
    )
);
$loop1 = new WP_Query($old_args);
$posts = array();

if ($loop1->have_posts()):
    while ($loop1->have_posts()):
        $loop1->the_post();
        $posts[] = $loop1->post->ID; // Storing the post_ID's result in array.
    endwhile;
else:
    echo "No product Found";
endif; //loop close
```

2nd query selecting the records that are not found

```
$new_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => '_sale_price_dates_to',
            'value' => $timenow,
            'compare' => '>=',
            'type' => 'numeric'
        ) ,
        array(
            'key' => '_sale_price_dates_to',
            'value' => '',
            'compare' => '!='
        ) ,
        array(
            'key' => 'wccaf_location_zipcode',
            'value' => array(
                '78774',
                '73344'
            ) ,
            'compare' => 'NOT IN'
        )
    ) ,
    'orderby' => 'meta_value',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $cat_id
        )
    )
);
$loop2 = new WP_Query($new_args);
$result_not_found_array = array();

if ($loop2->have_posts()):
    while ($loop2->have_posts()):
        $loop2->the_post();
        $posts[] = $loop2->post->ID; // Storing the post_ID's result in array.
    endwhile;
else:
    echo "No product Found";
endif; //loop close
```

Merging the results into third array

```
$post_ids = array_merge($result_found_array, $result_not_found_array);
$loop = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post__in' => $posts,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 5
));
```

Now I want result according to merge array index. I want to show result that are found first and the result that are not found at the last.
for example:- Merge array is `101,104,103,106`. Like that ,sequence I want my result.

Comment: Please properly format your code. Your query parameters in unreadable as it is in one llllooooonnnnnggggggg line.

Answer (score 0):

Use `orderby` `post__in`

```
$loop = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'post__in'       => $posts, 
        'paged'          => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'orderby'        => 'post__in'
    )
);
```

> Remember it is only available from version 3.5

Comment: If the answer worked for you, the best thank you is to accept it (click the check mark under the vote arrows on the left), and once you have enough reputation, you can also vote up answers that are helpful.